# Mostrar e receber resposta de um p:confirmDialog acionado através da Managed/CDI Bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, front-end

Tenho uma view com num botão de gravar, só que o método que é executado no botão gravar faz algumas verificações no bean e pergunta ao utilizador se quer realmente guardar. Mostrar o dialog:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance( ).execute( "PF('confG').show();" );
```

Como posso gravar os dados depois de ter tido uma resposta no Front-End, dada pelo utilizador no `p:confirmDialog`?

Comment: não é possível fazer o pretendido ?